# Yup conditionally extend Object Schema with other Schema

Tags: yup

For a Project I use [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) and I have some trouble extending a Schema when a property is set.

I build a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-johnson-njli8q?file=/index.ts) to show my Problem but the basics are the following.

```
// Schema I want to extend by, I use it in other places which is why I want to spread it into the baseSchema
const baseSchema = yup.object({
  firstName: yup.string().required()
}).required();

const extendedSchema = yup
  .object({
    hasOtherFields: yup
      .mixed()
      .required()
      .oneOf([...TRUE_FLASE])
  })
  .when("hasOtherFields", {
    is: (value?: typeof TRUE_FLASE[number]) =>
      value != null && value === "true",
    then: (schema) =>
      schema
        .shape({
          ...baseSchema.fields
        })
        .required()
  })
  .required();
```

So the property `hasOtherFields` needs to be set and needs to be either `"true"` or `"false"`. If it is `"true"`, I extend the `extendedSchema` with `shape` and pass in the fields from another the `baseSchema` which has a required string field.

Sadly this doesn't work ... If I create a nested `object` property inside the `object` declaration like so

```
const extendedSchema = yup
  .object({
    hasOtherFields: yup
      .mixed()
      .required()
      .oneOf([...TRUE_FLASE]),
    extendedFields: yup.object({}).when("hasOtherFields", {
      is: (value?: typeof TRUE_FLASE[number]) =>
        value != null && value === "true",
      then: (schema) =>
        schema
          .shape({
            ...baseSchema.fields
          })
          .required()
    })
  })
```

it works, but that doesn't really work for my use case.

So my question is, is there a way ? I basically want the type to look like this

```
type Schema = {hasCoApplicant: "false"} | {hasCoApplicant: "true"; firstName: string};
```

Comment: "Sadly this doesn't work", does it show some kind of error?

Comment: When I do `extendedSchema.validateSync({  hasOtherFields: "true"});` it passes validaiton, which it shouldnt, since `firstName` is missing.